# How to read the manual page for POSIX refering to error codes?

Tags: pthreads, posix, manual, manpage

I  am currently working with pthread and read the documentation from here: [Pthread Manual Pthread Join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html).

However, when I read  the pages I see the ERRORS, but not the corresponding return values, which will get returned from `pthread_join`. So my question is, are the ERRORS ordered in ascending order (since it might be an enumerator)?

Comment: No you can't assume anything about the values specified, except that they are int-compatible and never correspond to any possible return value in cases of success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error values such as `EDEADLK` are macros defined by including the `<errno.h>` header file.

Example:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

...

int retval = pthread_join( threadID, NULL );
if ( retval == EDEADLK )
{
    // error-handling code for deadlock
}
else if ( retval == EINVAL )
{
    // error-handling code for invalid thread id
}
else if ( retval == ESRCH  )
{
    // error-handling code for no such thread id
}
```

Note that the above code is correct only for Linux, as the only error number [specified by POSIX for `pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) is `EDEADLCK`.

Per [the POSIX standard for error numbers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_03), (bolded portions particularly relevant to your question):

> **2.3 Error Numbers**
>
> **Most functions can provide an error number. The means by which each
>   function provides its error numbers is specified in its description.**
>
> Some functions provide the error number in a variable accessed through
>   the symbol `errno`, defined by including the [`<errno.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html) header.
>   The value of `errno` should only be examined when it is indicated to
>   be valid by a function's return value. No function in this volume of
>   POSIX.1-2008 shall set `errno` to zero. For each thread of a process,
>   the value of `errno` shall not be affected by function calls or
>   assignments to `errno` by other threads.
>
> **Some functions return an error number directly as the function value. These functions return a value of zero to indicate success.**
>
> If more than one error occurs in processing a function call, any one
>   of the possible errors may be returned, as the order of detection is
>   undefined.
>
> Implementations may support additional errors not included in this
>   list, may generate errors included in this list under circumstances
>   other than those described here, or may contain extensions or
>   limitations that prevent some errors from occurring.
>
> The ERRORS section on each reference page specifies which error
>   conditions shall be detected by all implementations ("shall fail") and
>   which may be optionally detected by an implementation ("may fail"). If
>   no error condition is detected, the action requested shall be
>   successful. If an error condition is detected, the action requested
>   may have been partially performed, unless otherwise stated.
>
> Implementations may generate error numbers listed here under
>   circumstances other than those described, if and only if all those
>   error conditions can always be treated identically to the error
>   conditions as described in this volume of POSIX.1-2008.
>   Implementations shall not generate a different error number from one
>   required by this volume of POSIX.1-2008 for an error condition
>   described in this volume of POSIX.1-2008, but may generate additional
>   errors unless explicitly disallowed for a particular function.
>
> Each implementation shall document, in the conformance document,
>   situations in which each of the optional conditions defined in
>   POSIX.1-2008 is detected. The conformance document may also contain
>   statements that one or more of the optional error conditions are not
>   detected.
>
> Certain threads-related functions are not allowed to return an error
>   code of [EINTR]. Where this applies it is stated in the ERRORS section
>   on the individual function pages.
>
> **The following macro names identify the possible error numbers**, in the context of the functions specifically defined in this volume of
>   POSIX.1-2008; these general descriptions are more precisely defined in
>   the ERRORS sections of the functions that return them. Only these
>   macro names should be used in programs, since the actual value of the
>   error number is unspecified. All values listed in this section shall
>   be unique, except as noted below. The values for all these macros
>   shall be found in the [`<errno.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html) header defined in the Base
>   Definitions volume of POSIX.1-2008. The actual values are unspecified
>   by this volume of POSIX.1-2008.
>
> ```
> [E2BIG]
>     Argument list too long. The sum of the number of bytes
>     used by the new process image's argument list and environment
>     list is greater than the system-imposed limit of {ARG_MAX} bytes.
>
>     or:
>
>     Lack of space in an output buffer.
>
>     or:
>
>     Argument is greater than the system-imposed maximum.
> [EACCES]
>     Permission denied. An attempt was made to access a file
>     in a way forbidden by its file access permissions.
> [EADDRINUSE]
>     Address in use. The specified address is in use.
> [EADDRNOTAVAIL]
>     Address not available. The specified address is not
>     available from the local system.
> [EAFNOSUPPORT]
>     Address family not supported. The implementation does
>     not support the specified address family, or the specified
>     address is not a valid address for the address family
>     of the specified socket.
> [EAGAIN]
>     Resource temporarily unavailable. This is a temporary
>     condition and later calls to the same routine may complete
>     normally.
> [EALREADY]
>     Connection already in progress. A connection request is already
>     in progress for the specified socket.
>     .
>     .
>     .
> ```